# Problems with Javascript Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am currently trying to write a script to determine the minimum number of "jumps" you can make in an array to get back to the initial starting number.  The starting number is always the biggest number in the array.

As an example if the array was `[2, 3, 5, 6, 1]` then the starting number would be 6 because it is the biggest.  You can then jump 6 positions either left or right (you can choose) and where you end up is your next number.  Lets say we went right, we would end up at `1` because we would loop back to the beginning of the array.  You could then go `1` left and end up back at the `6` again.  Therefore the minimum number of jumps is **2**.

I wrote the below functions to take the input array and determine the minimum number of jumps, however, the recursion in the `search()` function is not working as I would hope / expect.

Each search function call calls itself 2 times (once for left, and once for right), however the constantly incrementing `count` variable gets "confused".  Once one line of recursion ends (when `count>arr.length`) I would expect it to go back to the previous step and do the right line of recursion.  But the `count` variable does not revert to the previous step (it stays as it is) and therefore the entire function just stops.

TL DR:  How do you make a javascript functions variables maintain what they are even when the function is called again and the variables are overwritten?

```
function ArrayJumping(arr) { 
  //Find the largest number
  var startingPos=arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, arr));
  //Find the multiple we are searching for
  var multiple=arr.length;
  return search(startingPos,multiple,arr,startingPos+1,0);
}
function search(pos,mult,arr,target,count) {
  if (count>arr.length) {
    return false;
  }
  var tpos=pos+1;
  if ((tpos==target && count!=0) || (tpos%target==0 && count!=0)) {
    return count;
  }
  for (var direction=-1;direction<=1;direction+=2) {
    nPos=getRealPos(pos+(direction*arr[pos]),arr);
    var result=search(nPos,mult,arr,target,count+1);
    if (result!=false) {
      return result;
    }
  }
}

function getRealPos(n,numArr) {
  if (n>=0) {
    while (n>numArr.length) {
      n-=numArr.length;
    }
  } else {
    while (n<0) {
      n+=numArr.length;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: sorry what's the question again? It's a bit misleading, can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Basicly @Leo, when you call a function from within itself, all the variables that are parsed to the function are overwritten with the new ones (it is the same function) this is a problem when you want to call the function from itself TWICE using variables relative to the first call.  Because you call it once and the first call's variables are overwritten